# Org Mode link to open directory in Dired

Tags: org-mode, osx, directories

I'd like to have a link like

```
[[file:~/projects][Projects]]
```

open directly in Dired rather than Finder (I'm on a Mac), which is what it does now.  Is there a way?  (Of course there's a way.  It's Emacs.)

Comment: Do you want `file:` links to open in diredit, or would you maybe like to add a new link type (such as `diredit:`) to org mode?

Comment: Either would be OK, I think.

Comment: You can read how to add a hyperlink type in the org manual here: http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html When I get the chance, I'll put together a proper answer for you.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but what's "diredit"? The built-in directory editor is called [Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html), so it might just be a typo? If it's an add-on package, it would be great if you could add an appropriate link to your question.

Comment: @itsjeyd - yep, typo, fixed. thanks!

Comment: No problem :) Have you tried opening `[[file:~/projects][Projects]]` in vanilla Emacs (launched via `emacs -Q`)? I'm on Linux, and `org-mode` opens directory links in Dired by default. I don't see why the default behavior should be different for OS X.

Comment: Have not; Emacs on OS X is packaged as an app (i.e., no `-Q` option on command line).  At any rate, my use case is for the full app -- but it's good to know the behavior on Linux now.

Comment: @JohnJ Just FYI you can type `open -a Emacs.app --args -Q` on the command line on OS X

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways.  First, typing `C-u C-c C-o` on a link should force it to be opened in emacs, rather than in an external app.  Second, you can permanently override the default behavior by adding an entry to the variable `org-file-apps`:

```
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '(directory . emacs))
```

which tells org-mode to use dired for all directory links.  Alternatively, you could use `customize-variable` to achieve the same.

The reason that the default behavior is different between OS X and Linux is that `org-file-apps-default-macosx` contains a fall-through entry `(t . "open %s")`

Answer (score 27):

You can modify the link description as follows :

```
     [[file+emacs:~/projects][Projects]]
```

It will open the link in Emacs with typing `C-c C-o`.

Comment: FYI: it works but when `M-x org-lint` it shows `Deprecated "file+emacs" link type`. org-version 9.2.6

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind writing/executing lisp code you could do:

```
[[elisp: (find-file "~/projects")][Projects]]
```

This is what I do.

Maybe there are other possibilities if you check the manual carefully at https://orgmode.org/manual/External-Links.html

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, with a link like this:

```
[[file:~/projects][Projects]]
```

Left mouse click opens the directory in File Explorer.

Right mouse click opens the directory in dired.